# C# XML reader trying to read from a XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to read from an xml file which is not always the same pattern and the goal is to read from the file and sort the gathered data to Arrays so later i can make use out of the sorted data for example...

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<imgdir name="Eqp.img">
    <imgdir name="Eqp">
        <imgdir name="Accessory">
            <imgdir name="1010000">
                <string name="name" value="Long Brown Beard"/>
            </imgdir>
            <imgdir name="1010001">
                <string name="name" value="Goatee"/>
            </imgdir>
            <imgdir name="1010002">
                <string name="name" value="Ninja Mask for Men"/>
            </imgdir>
            <imgdir name="1010003">
                <string name="name" value="5 O'Clock Shadow"/>
            </imgdir>
            <imgdir name="1010004">
                <string name="name" value="General's Mustache (1)"/>
            </imgdir>
            <imgdir name="1010005">
                <string name="name" value="General's Mustache (2)"/>
            </imgdir>
          </imgdir>
        <imgdir name="Face">
            <imgdir name="1010006">
                <string name="name" value="Yakuza Scar"/>
            </imgdir>
            <imgdir name="1011000">
                <string name="name" value="Ninja Mask for Women"/>
            </imgdir>
            <imgdir name="1011001">
                <string name="name" value="SF Ninja Mask"/>
            </imgdir>
          </imgdir>
```

And this is my code

```
Uri uri = new Uri(path);
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path);
int x = 0;
int Row_length = 0;
#region Check Rows Length in File
//===================================================================================================
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList elemList = root.GetElementsByTagName("imgdir");
for (x = 0; x < elemList.Count; x++) ;
DisplayChanges_Box.Text += ("Total Elements Count= " + x + '\n' + "XML File= " + filename + '\n');
Row_length = x;

#endregion
int CurrentArrayDataBox = 0;
int[] itemIDArray = new int[x + 1];
string[] itemNamesArray = new string[x + 1];
int LastRow = Row_length;

while (reader.Read())
{
    if (reader.IsStartElement())
    {
        if (reader.HasAttributes)
        {
            //    <<Checking if the current elemnt is a number or Group Name such as Weapons...Gloves...etc>>
            string ItemNumberAsString;
            int ItemNumber;
            string ItemDescription;
            ItemNumberAsString = reader.GetAttribute("name");
            bool parsed = Int32.TryParse(ItemNumberAsString, out ItemNumber);
            if (parsed)
            {
                reader.ReadToNextSibling("string");
                ItemDescription = reader.GetAttribute("string");
                //    <<Write To ID and Names Array the gained data values>>
                itemIDArray[CurrentArrayDataBox] = ItemNumber;
                itemNamesArray[CurrentArrayDataBox] = ItemDescription;
                CurrentArrayDataBox++;
                reader.ReadToFollowing("imgdir");
            }
            else if (!parsed)
            {
                reader.ReadToFollowing("imgdir");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

================
The program is supposed to sort the information like this...
Each time it checks current attribute to Detect if it is a string Like:

```
"Eqp.img"
"Eqp"
"Accessory"
```

ignore them
or if it is

```
"1010000"
"1010001"
"1010002"
"1010003"
...
```

store the numbers in `ItemIDArray` and their String Name value to store in ItemNamesArray

currently i cant seem to be able to get numbers only detect if it is a String and while the attribute is Number it shows it as "Name" instead of the real number

Sincerely yours.

Comment: Why are you reading it with an XmlReader *and* reading the whole thing into an XmlDocument? (I'd encourage you to use LINQ to XML in general - it's a *much* nicer XML API.)

Comment: I'd generally try to avoid using XmlReader unless you really, really need it. LINQ to XML is likely to be much simpler here. It's not really clear what the issue is though - particularly as "it shows it as" doesn't explain *what* is showing anything.

Comment: well when it reads the value instead of displaying the numbers while debuging it shows value as "Name" , and about linq.. well im just used to XMLreader

Comment: Well if you *want* your code to be difficult to understand, go ahead... but I promise you it would be simpler to use LINQ to XML. As for "it shows value as Name" - the value of what? It's really unclear what you're seeing. It would be easier to help you if you wrote a console app with expected output and actual output - see [mcve].

Comment: on first read it shows ItemNumberAsString integer as
"Eqp.img" than "Eqp" and "Accessory" but when it should start showing Numbers "1010000" "1010001" it shows "name" instead of displaying numbers it never success gather numbers from attribute that is the big issue

Comment: Well have a look at your XML. What's the value of the XML attribute "name" in the element `<string name="name" value="Goatee"/>`? (And again, repeatedly saying "it shows" in an unclear way makes it much harder to help you than providing a [mcve] as a console app, with actual output and expected output...)

Comment: Having 4 different layers with the same tag name is going to make parsing file very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The following code checks if the imgdir node has a string child.

```
private bool ReadNameAndValue(XmlNode parent, out string name, out string value)
{
    name = "";
    value = "";

    var node = parent.SelectSingleNode("./string");
    if (node == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    try
    {
        name = parent.SelectSingleNode("./string/@name").InnerText;
        value = parent.SelectSingleNode("./string/@value").InnerText;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
    }

    return true;
}

public void ParseDoc(string fileName = @"c:\temp\soexample.xml")
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(fileName);

    var elements = doc.SelectNodes("//imgdir");

    foreach (XmlNode node in elements)
    {
        string name;
        string value;
        if (ReadNameAndValue(node, out name, out value))
        {
            string id = node.SelectSingleNode("./@name").InnerText;
            Console.WriteLine("Id: " + id + ", Name: " + name + ", Value: " + value);

            //do whatever you want with the id, name and value
        }
    }
}
```

The printout of this is

```
Id: 1010000, Name: name, Value: Long Brown Beard
Id: 1010001, Name: name, Value: Goatee
Id: 1010002, Name: name, Value: Ninja Mask for Men
Id: 1010003, Name: name, Value: 5 O'Clock Shadow
Id: 1010004, Name: name, Value: General's Mustache (1)
Id: 1010005, Name: name, Value: General's Mustache (2)
Id: 1010006, Name: name, Value: Yakuza Scar
Id: 1011000, Name: name, Value: Ninja Mask for Women
Id: 1011001, Name: name, Value: SF Ninja Mask
```

Answer (score 0):

As Jon suggests, LINQ to XML would be far simpler here, and a lot more readable.  This is one way you could approach it:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(path);

var items = from imgdir in doc.Descendants("imgdir")
            let name = (string)imgdir.Attribute("name")
            from id in TryParseInteger(name)
            from description in imgdir.Elements("string").Attributes("value").Take(1)
            select new {Id = id, Description = description.Value};
```

Where `TryParseInteger` is implemented like so:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> TryParseInteger(string value)
{
    int result;

    if (int.TryParse(value, out result))
    {
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2Gungl) for a working example.